# mdx typed member properties when not in a "with member" statement

Tags: select, properties, mdx, member

I've been bagning my head on this one for a few days and could really need some insight.

In a MDX select statement you can create a member like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Legal Closing Date] as [Entity].[Entity].CurrentMember.Properties("Legal Closing Date", TYPED)
```

and then use that in the select to get the values in a strongly typed manner.

Is there any way to get the same result (having a strongly typed date, in my case) when accessing that property in the following manner:

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Total Commitment]} ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY [Investee].[Entity].[All].Children
DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    [Entity].[Entity].[Legal Closing Date],
    MEMBER_CAPTION, 
    MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
ON ROWS
FROM 
[FIA_DM]
```

Using this manner, the ssrs report I have that is based on this select statement sees the date as a string and even a cdate returns errors because it incorrecly interprets the first digits as the month when it is actually the day, etc.

I know that technically, I should be able to use the WITH statement and I would get, as per my examples, the same result (only with a typed date), but I simplfied my select statement here and because I use other dimensions on rows (crossjoining them), using the WITH statement brings quite a few other headaches.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible to get the member property's typed value with the Properties function.

- Mosha Pasumansky has a [post in his (old) blog about it](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2004/11/13/typed-member-properties-and-mdx-properties-function.aspx);
- While it's mentioned on MDSN's reference page for [Properties MDX function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144821.aspx) on how to get the strongly typed value of the member property, there's no mention about it on the [PROPERTIES keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145613.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that if you want the typed date, you have to use the WITH MEMBER approach and cannot use the DIMENSION PROPERTIES syntax.